# Python: Find the size of a binary tree implemented in dictionary with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

For a homework task we make a recursive function to find the amount of subjects of a binary tree implemented in a dictionary.

I know how to traverse in a binary tree but I don't know how to implement this in a recursive function.

I already got something like this:

```
def count_the_subjects(tree):
    if 'name' in tree:
    a = a + 1
    if 'name' in tree['children'][0]:
           tree = tree['children'][0]
           count_the_subjects(tree)
    elif 'name' in tree['children'][1]:
           tree = tree['children'][1]
           count_the_subjects(tree)'
```

Input looks like this:

```
count_the_subjects({'name': 'GAS', 'grade': 0.8, 'children': [{'name': 'CSA', 'grade': 0.5, 'children': [None, {'name': 'TA', 'grade': 0.6}]}, {'name': 'IP', 'grade': 0.99}]})
```

Output should look like this:

```
4
```

Comment: You need to return something from the function and you need to add the results of the recursive calls to something.

Comment: 1) Don't re-assign tree within `if` and `elif`. That way you lose the original object. May be just get rid of the variable completely: `count_the_subjects(tree['children'][0])` and similar for the other condition. 2) It should not be `if` and `elif`. It should instead of two separate ifs. (Dry run to know why :)). 3) You should increment `a` with the results of 2 recursive calls. Finally don't forget to return `a` after `ifs`.